# Unresolved "To the power of half"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, intuition

I have seen many formula to resolve this but everyone have tried to make it logical,to say square it and multiply two exponents, such as $(x^{\frac{1}{2}})^2 = x^{\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2} = x^1$.

But I am searching an explanation in terms of repeated multiplication: for example, $2^3$ means $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$, but how this can be extended to understand why $16^{\frac {1}{2}}$ means $\sqrt{16}$?

Is it impossible to multiply 16 by itself 1/2 times,if possible what is the algebric expression without any variable i mean using only 16 and 1/2?

Comment: Please change the tag. This question has nothing to do with abstract algebra.

Comment: Do you mean some number $x$ to the power of $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: I can't get what you mean by "two exponents such as **external e.g 2 and internal 2/1**."

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Internal and external to what? $2$ is an integer and $\frac{2}{1}$ is a fraction, but $\frac{2}{1}=2$ so what do the words 'internal' and 'external' refer to?

Comment: @Noman, I have tried to edit the question to clarify what I think was your intention (in particular what you mean by "internal" and "external", and what kind of explanation you are hoping for). If I have overstepped, please feel free to revert back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your question, I assume you are asking not for an algebraic demonstration of why "to the 1/2 power" means "square root", but rather an intuitive explanation of why it *should* mean that.  Here is my best attempt at explaining why that makes sense.

Suppose I ask you the question:  What number is halfway between $6$ and $96$?

You might reason as follows:  To get from $6$ to $96$, I add $90$.  If I want to break that up into two equal steps, I could think of it as adding $45$, then adding $45$ again.  The value in the middle would be what I get if I start with $6$ and add $45$ -- in other words, $51$.

That would be a perfectly reasonable explanation and answer if you are only able to think of getting from one number to another by way of *addition*.  But there is another perspective on the question, one that thinks of getting from one number to another by way of *multiplication*.

That second way of reasoning goes as follows:  To get from $6$ to $96$, you multiply by $16$.  Now ask yourself:

> How do I break the operation "multiply by $16$" into two equal "half-steps"?

A naïve first answer might be to think:  "Half of $16$ is $8$, so I multiply by $8$ twice."  But it's easy to see that doesn't work:   If you start with $6$, multiply by $8$, then multiply by $8$ again, you definitely don't end up at $96$.

What *does* work is to think:

> "If I multiply by $4$, then multiply by $4$ again, the result is the
>   same as just multiplying by $16$ in a single step."

And you can check this:  Start with $6$, multiply by $4$ to get $24$, then multiply by $4$ again to get $96$.  The number "in the middle" is $24$.

So there are two different types of reasoning involved:  *Additive reasoning* and *Multiplicative reasoning*:

- According to additive reasoning, "half of $+90$" means $+45$, and the number halfway between $6$ and $96$ is $51$.  This is called the *arithmetic mean* (or just the *average*) of $6$ and $96$.
- According to multiplicative reasoning, "half of $\times 16$" means $\times 4$, and the number halfway between $6$ and $96$ is $24$.  This is called the *geometric mean* of $6$ and $96$.

To understand why $16^{1/2}$ means "the square root of $16$", you have to reason multiplicatively. As you know, $16^5$ means "multiply $5$ factors of $16$ together".  Likewise for any positive whole number $k$, $16^k$ means "multiply $k$ factors of $16$ together."  In both cases, we are thinking multiplicatively, not additively.  So to make sense of $16^{1/2}$ we should understand it as meaning "Multiplying by $16$ 'half of one time'."  As the discussion above explains, the only sensible interpretation of that is that it means "Multiply by $4$".

Comment: Is it impossible to multiply 16 by itself 1/2 times,if possible what is the algebric expression without any variable i mean using only 16 and 1/2?

Comment: 16 multiply by 4=64,as we know that 16 to the power of half is 4?

Comment: @Noman I am not sure what you are asking beyond what is already in the answer.  Yes, it is possible to multiply 16 by itself 1/2 a time. You just have to understand that in the sense of "Break the operation of multiplying by 16 into two equal sub-operations; each of those is '1/2 a time.'"

Answer (score 3):

From the idea of exponentiation as repeated multiplication we notice certain principles such as

$$ b^m\cdot b^n=b^{m+n} $$

in the case of natural numbers. But then we notice that these principles can be extended for fractional exponents if we follow the same rules, such as

$$ 16^{1/2}\cdot 16^{1/2}=16^{1/2\,+\,1/2}=16^1=16$$

so we conclude that this only makes sense if $16^{1/2}=4$.

Following the same rule we can make sense of a zero exponent if we consider examples such as

$$ 5^1\cdot5^{0}=5^{1+0}=5^1=5$$

so conclude that it must be the case that $5^0=1$.

Then we can consider negative exponents, etc.

Comment: how much time i need to multiply 16 with 16?

Comment: This is not an algorithm for multiplication so I don't understand the concern with how much time it takes to multiply 16 by 16.

Comment: I think @Noman means "How many times do I multiply $16$ by itself?" He is looking for an interpretation of $16^{1/2}$ in terms of repeated multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

When we have an initial definition such as "$b^n$ means be multiplied by itself $n$ times" that is only a base definition for whole numbers $n$.

And analogy would be the definition of "$n \times m$ means $n$ added to itself $m$ times".  This may be true but then how can we explain "$4/5 \times 1/2$".  It is, after all, impossible to add something to itself 1/2 times.

Instead we have the concept of "extending" a definition.  If $m \times n$ is $m$ added to itself we can imagine defining a number $v/m$ as "the number that when added to itself $m$ times is equal to $v$"  Or in other words "$v/m$ is the number such that $v/m \times m = v$".

But now we have a problem that "$n \times v/m$ means $n$ added to itself $v/m$ times" no longer makes sense.

So we "extend" the definition.  We note if $v/m \times m = v$ then $n \times v/m \times m = n \times v$ so "$n \times v/m$ means the number that when added  to itself is $m$ times is $n \times v$ or $n$ added to itself $v$ times".

So $b^n$ is the exact same type of situation.

We note $b^nb^m = b^{n+m}$.  Now we can't multiply $b$ times itself a zero number of times so $b^0$ by our initial definition makes no sense.  But if $b^0$ did equal anything we would have $b^0b^n = b^{n+0} = b^n$ so $b^0 = 0$.  We "extend" the definition to include that.

Similarly if we extend the definition to include $b^{-n}b^{n}= b^{n-n} = b^0 =1$ to include "$b^{-n} = 1/b^n$ if $-n < 0$".

If we actually had to spell out what $b^n$ is defined as now it'd be a bit complicated but acceptable:  "$b^n$ is $b$ multiplied by itself if $n$ is a positive whole number at least two but if not then if the is another whole number $m$  at least two, so that $n + m$ is a positive whole number at least to then $b^n$ is the number so that $b^{n}b^m = b^{n+m}$ which is just another way of saying $b^1 = b$ and $b^0 = 1$ and $b^{-n} = 1/b^n$ if $-n < 0$ but $n$ is an integer".

Now for $b > 1$ we now that there exists a unique number $\sqrt[n]{b}$ such that $\sqrt[n]{b}^n = b$.  We also know that for $n \in \mathbb Z$ that $(b^n)^m = b^{nm}$.  We can extend the definition that "$b^{1/n}$ is the number such that $(b^{1/n})^n= b^{n/n} = b^1 = b$... in other words $b^{1/n} = \sqrt[n]{b}$".

This is an *extended* definition.  We no longer are saying "$b^{1/2}$ is $b$ multiplied by itself 1/2 times".  We are saying "$b^{1/2}$ is the number that when multiplied by itself $2$ times is $b$".  And that is a perfectly valid *extended* definition.

Just as $"n \times 1/2$ is the number that when added to itself $2$ times is n" is the extended definition when "$n$ added to itself $1/2$ times" no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

We have the power law,
$$(a^m)^n = a^{mn} \tag 1$$
Furthermore, we have
$$(\sqrt{a})^2 = a \tag 2$$
So we can now ask: Does it make sense to write $\sqrt{a}$ as a power, too, and if so, what power does it have to be?

Well, let's answer the second question first, by formally writing $\sqrt{a} = a^x$. Inserting into (2) then gives
$$(a^x)^2 = a$$
Now we can apply (1), to get
$$a^{2x} = a$$
Now we know $a^1=a$, therefore for the exponential to make sense, we should have $2x=1$, that is $x=\frac12$. Therefore we get
$$\sqrt{a} = a^{1/2}$$

Indeed, it is possible to extend the power this way to all rational numbers, that is numbers that can be written as $q=\frac{m}{n}$, by
$$a^q = a^{m/n} = \sqrt[n]{a^m}$$

Now to the second question, does it make sense? Well, one can verify that all the power laws still hold, as long as $a>0$, and in those cases one also does not get any contradiction or undefined values. Therefore this definition is, indeed, meaningful.

Comment: This is a good algebraic proof, but it is precisely the kind of explanation the OP said he is *not* asking for (see the 1st paragraph of the question).